# how to convert my Acivitity material toolbar to fragment

Tags: java, android

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{

Toolbar toolbar;
TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager viewPager;
ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment,
            container, false);
    toolbar=(Toolbar)view.findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    tabLayout=(TabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    viewPager=(ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPagerAdapter=new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new OneFragment(),"Home");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new TwoFragment(),"Pixel");

    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    return view;
}
```

}

when I use this code as a fragment then it shows wrong `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`  and `getSupportFragmentManager()`. How to solve it in fragment.

Comment: you must extends from android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Comment: How do I can extends from android.support.v4.app.Fragment ?

Comment: in your class, from which class Fragment extends ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below way;

```
 ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

and

```
    viewPagerAdapter=new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
```

Comment: It doesn't work getActivity().setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

Comment: viewPagerAdapter=new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity()); In this case, that is showing wrong   getActivity().   @Vishal Vaishnav

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I have solved from your advice. I used ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar); and viewPagerAdapter=new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

Answer (score 0):

Both methods are for an `Activity`. You should let the handling of the `ToolBar` for the Activity which the Fragment resides inside. In other words: move your `ToolBar` layout to the Activity layout and manage it from there.

Comment: I already used toolbar activity. but I couln't convert activity code to fragment code. When I created this code on activity that was ok but when I have written in fragment that is going to error. @MK

Answer (score 0):

Add toolbar in the Activity. You can handle toolbar in Activity in which the fragment resides and if you want have multiple fragments and want to  pass any data to be displayed in the the toolbar with respect to each fragment, you can use Event Bus to pass data from each fragment to Activity.

Comment: I already used toolbar activity. but I couln't convert activity code  to fragment code. When I created this code on activity that was ok but when I have written in fragment that is going to error. @Eby Cloudins